Error when i run commend php composer dump-autoload

Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Error

  Class "Composer\InstalledVersions" not found

  at vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Cache/CacheManager.php:43
     39▕      * @return MemoryCache
     40▕      */
     41▕     public function createMemoryDriver(): CacheInterface
     42▕     {
  ➜  43▕         if (!InstalledVersions::satisfies(new VersionParser, 'psr/simple-cache', '^3.0')) {
     44▕             return new MemoryCacheDeprecated(
     45▕                 config('excel.cache.batch.memory_limit', 60000)
     46▕             );
     47▕         }

      +11 vendor frames

  12  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1


What is Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts? And then postAutoloadDump?
What is causing this?
I tried to change database password and server, did not yield any different results. Should it?
What is class "Composer\InstalledVersions" and why is it not found during caching for the maatwebsite/excel package? I'm just dumping the autoloader with the help of composer, how is that memory driver supposed to already interact while the vendor folder is being build? Is that package totally broken?

Please add the actual command in your shell and all the output it creates verbatim. See [help] how to use the editor and [edit] your question.

This is a hen-and-egg problem.
Run composer install without any scripts (--no-scripts, --no-plugins switches) and afterwards run composer dump-autoload to re-trigger all the scripts that currently fail.
Laravel hooks on the dump-autoload event; disabling scripts during install ensures you get all dependencies (incl. interfaces like 'psr/simple-cache) fully installed and satisfied before being used in scripts.
Also double-check you're using the latest Composer version and the general Composer troubleshooting recommendations. Especially the first five points are just an easy count of fingers and less than a hand full of work that can save quite some headaches.
From your question there is a slight chance you may also run out of memory, if scripts are triggering large file loads with the excel spreadsheet importer, consider to blank out such files for further trouble-shooting.
